# How to fix highchart navigation and step based on selected range?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is there a way to fix highchart [navigation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator) duration and force step based on selected [range](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector)?

For example if 1 day range is selected navigation will step on per day

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0,
    buttons: [ {
        type: "minute",
        count: 60,
        text: "1h"
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }]
},
navigator: {
    xAxis: {
        tickWidth: 1,
        lineWidth: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        tickPixelInterval: 200,
        range: 113600000,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            style: {
                color: '#888'
            },
            x: 3,
            y: -4
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/tu44Lhx4/)

Comment: Do you mean set different tickInterval in navigator ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan: I disabled navigator which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled navigator and used rangeSelector to fix the duration.

```
rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0,
            buttons: [ {
                type: "minute",
                count: 60,
                text: "1h"
            }, {
                type: "minute",
                count: 180,
                text: "3h"
            }, {
                type: "minute",
                count: 300,
                text: "5h"
            }]
},
navigator: {
  enabled: false
}
```